# Is the additive discrete Logarithm problem always easy in Fields?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, finite-field

While thinking about additive DH key exchanges, I somehow had the idea that additive DH key exchange may *always* be easy to break, *if we are in a field*.

So here's (directly) the question:
**In *any* finite field, is the *additive* discrete logarithm and / or the computational diffie-hellman problem *always* easy?**

Here's some more info on the details:

- It can safely be assumed that doing addition and multiplication is fast
- The additive discrete logarithm problem in a field $(\mathbb F,+,\cdot)$ is to find the smallest $k\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that such that $Q=k\odot P$ holds for given $Q,P\in\mathbb F$, where $\odot$ denotes repeated addition of an element to itself k-times (as usual).
- If solving these problems isn't *always* easy, I'd also be interested whether there are certain properties of the field that would make it easy.

Comment: Note that adding $P$ to itself $k$ times isn't the same as using the field's multiplication operation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos OK, I see that my notation may be unclear / confusing here, lemme try and fix that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes it is, because $k\cdot x = (k\cdot 1) \times x$, and it is natural to identify $k$ with $k\cdot 1$.

Comment: @fkraiem Consider a binary extension field. $P+P=0$, but $2\cdot P$ is not.

Comment: @CodesInChaos In a binary field, $2 = 0$.

Comment: @fkraiem I'm talking about extension fields, like $2^x$  with $x>1$. Multiplication propagates across "digits"/coefficients, addition does not.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have no idea what you are saying, but the fact that the only way to meaningfully define 2 in a field of characteristic 2 is by 2 = 0.

Comment: @fkraiem The convention for binary fields I'm used to is that each bit in the number corresponds to one coefficient. So 2 is $1 x^1+ 0 x^0$

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ok I see, you note $2$ the element represented by the binary string `10`. I guess that makes sense, though coming from a more mathy background I can hardly imagine $2$ as anything other than $1+1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will call the field elements "points" (as an analogy with elliptic curves). We can thus add points together and multiply points together. We can also multiply a point with an integer with a double-and-add algorithm (which will be reasonably efficient), and, similarly, raise a point to some integer power with a square-and-multiply algorithm.

Your additive Diffie-Hellman thus looks like this:

- There is a conventional base point $G$.
- The two parties select random integers $a$ and $b$ respectively, and compute $aG$ and $bG$ (point $G$ multiplied by an integer), that they send to each other.
- They then both compute the common secret $a(bG) = b(aG) = abG$.

The attacker's goal is to find that secret.

Now if the field's order is a known integer $q$ then the attacker has it easy:

$$ (aG)(bG)(G^{q-2}) = abG^q = abG $$

Note that while this breaks Diffie-Hellman in that specific context, this does not mean that the attacker can break Discrete Logarithm *per se*.

---

If the field order is *not* known, then things become more interesting. What the equation above basically says is that the attacker, by multiplying the observed points $aG$ and $bG$, gets $abG^2$, and he wants $abG$, so what he needs is to multiply that value by $1/G$. So the problem really is: if the field order is not known, then can the attacker compute the inverse of the base point?

If $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, then its order $q = p^f$ for a prime $p$ and an integer $f$; $p$ is the field *characteristic*. For any point $X$ in $\mathbb{F}$, we have $pX = 0$. Thus, the additive order of $G$ is necessarily $p$ (the integers $a$ and $b$ are really integers modulo $p$). For the DH problem to be interesting, we must thus assume that $p$ is relatively large (and therefore odd). Correspondingly, $f$ must be rather small, otherwise the field elements will be unwieldy (very large in RAM). For instance, if $p$ is at least 200 bits in length (for "100-bit security" in DH) and field elements fit in 10000 bits when encoded, then $f$ can be no more than 50.

Therefore, if the group additive order ($p$) is known, then the attacker can exhaustively try successive values of $f$ (starting from 1), each time assuming $q = p^f$ and then trying to compute the inverse of $G$ as $1/G = G^{q-2}$.

If $p$ is not known either, then we are in a mythical "generic field" which is like the "generic group" but with two operations, and then I think that DH in the additive group would be fairly safe. The only problem here is that there is no proof that a generic field can exist at all (just like the generic group, because it would imply all sorts of things such as $P \neq NP$), and I have no idea how to build a plausible candidate. For generic *groups*, elliptic curves are one of our best approximations, and yet we know more about them than just having an addition on them (indeed, we can compute curve orders with [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm)).

**Summary:** to make the additive DH safe, you would need *at least* your finite field to be such that its order *and* its characteristic (which is the additive order of your DH group) are totally unknown, and that seems to be a lot to ask for.

Comment: In the first part, do you mean that the multiplicative order (instead of additive order) is a divisor of $q-1$?

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast Mmh yes, that part was faulty (and confusing), I removed it.

Comment: can I say that DH with an additive group is broken in a field, even though I can use the additive notation with a multiplicative group in a field? My intuition is yes I can, but these terms are confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Since you ask whether the DL is *always* easy in *any* finite field, here is a perhaps silly view.

Let $E$ be some elliptic curve of prime order $p$, chosen carefully such that the DLP is hard. Let $P\in E$ be an arbitrary point other than $\mathcal{O}$, necessarily of prime order. Now consider the following straightforward map $$E\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$$ by $Q\mapsto n$, where $n$ is such that $Q=nP$. It should be easily checked that this is a group homomorphism, and in fact an isomorphism. Using this, we can define a multiplication on $E$. That is, for $Q_1,Q_2\in E$, such that $Q_1=n_1P$ and $Q_2=n_2P$, we define $Q_1\cdot Q_2 = n_1n_2P$. It should be easily checked that by this multiplication $E$ becomes a field (which additive group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and multiplicative group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$). In other words, $E$ can be thought of as isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Thus solving the additive DLP in $\mathbb{F}_p$, if represented this way, becomes hard, as it is reduced to solving the DLP on $E$.

Comment: The question assumes that the field operations are easy to compute, however.

Comment: True, that assumption does definitely not hold. On the other hand, scalar multiplication is efficient, which is essentially what we want for DH. So this would be a finite field in which additive DH can be efficiently computed, and the additive DLP is hard. Indeed not exactly what was asked for, but hopefully still interesting!

Comment: @fkraiem The question states "It can safely be assumed that doing addition and multiplication is fast"