# Is inverse polynomial in a finite field NP hard?

Tags: public-key, hardness-assumptions

In ECC we have: if we know $G$ and $P=kG$, it is very difficult to find $k$. I wonder whether or not in NTRUEncrypt: if we know $h$ and $P=rh$, it is difficult to find $r$?

Comment: [More abstract Q&A, but should cover this if the stucture at hand is a finite field.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41420/23623)

Comment: Aren't inverses in a field trivial since the order is known? $a^{-1} = a^{q-1}$, which you can compute in $\log(q)$ time

Comment: @bmm6o: you are right in a field of known order. I think the extended GCD allows to perform that in a field of unknown order. But as far as I understand (which is, not much), NTRUEncrypt does not operate in a field. If I'm right, that makes the title of the question wrong. Also: is the question to find $r$, or to find _an_ $r$, or the/an $r$ _with coefficient all in the set $\{-1,0,1\}$_ (which I think is what breaks NTRUEncrypt)?

Comment: Yeah, for this question I have a stronger grasp on the math angle than the crypto context, so hopefully my comment isn't worthless.

Comment: Since you know the maths angle please edit the  question stating the mathematical question precisely for everyone's benefit. NTRU is not exactly the best known cryptosystem out there.

Comment: NTRUEncrypt works modulo a polynomial over GF(q) (typically $x^n\pm1$). As @fgrieu said, polynomial GCD allows to invert elements easily. There can be non-invertible elements though, but it's rather rare (but non-negligible). There is definitely no hardness here.